# socket connection not getting from linux to windows platform

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, pragma, pack

I using socket in java. the data is coming from server which is on linux machine and i  want to get that data to window using socket. on same linux to linux socket connect but linux to window connection is getting. so please tell me the solution.... is there any other library required or something else?
Also how to solve pragma pack issue in java?

Comment: please post some code..

Comment: Did you remember to create a firewall exception?